# VB.net - How to add if after bat execute is completed?

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I tried to execute a bat file in a textbox. I succeeded and now I want to add an if after execution is completed to see if it was succeeded. How to do that?

My code:

```
        Using P As Process = New Process
        P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        P.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "E:\Desktop"
        P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        P.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\Desktop\test.bat"
        P.Start()
        Dim sOutput As String
        Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = P.StandardOutput
            sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
        TextBox1.Text = sOutput
        P.Close()
    End Using
```

The If:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\MyFile.txt") = False Then
            MsgBox("Field does not exist!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "File Not Found")
        Else
            MsgBox("Field exists!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "File Found")
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either synchronously wait for the process to finish:

```
p.WaitForExit(10000)  ' wait at most 10 000 ms
```

or you can asynchronusly subscribe to the process' [Exited event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
p.EnableRaisingEvents = True

AddHandler p.Exited, 
    Sub(sender, e)
        MsgBox("Process finished")
    End Sub

p.Start()
```

Comment: Problem on "Sub(sender, e)"

Comment: @1nikolas: Solution on "Sub(sender, e)". No, seriously, could you be a *little* more specific? It [compiles on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SpYYH7).

Comment: @Heinzi : He might be targeting .NET 3.5 or lower. In that case lambda expressions don't exist.

Comment: @VisualVincent: The above code should work perfectly fine in VS 2010 and above targeting .NET 3.5. Multi-line lambdas are a feature of the compiler, not of the framework. (If he's using some older version of VS, he should really mention that in the question...)

Comment: Oh you're right! How come nobody's ever told me this before? I've answered so many questions saying they don't work in .NET 3.5. :/

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/FJ9bR7r.png
http://i.imgur.com/WXYAHtv.png
http://i.imgur.com/4pLE19i.png
http://i.imgur.com/M0SJnhe.png
http://i.imgur.com/zW3HxVH.png
(5 pictures)

Comment: @1nikolas: The error means: you cannot use the variable names `sender` and `e` for the inner sub, because your outer sub already uses them. Use, for example `Sub(_sender, _e)` instead.

Comment: @Heinzi: Thanks! I know only the basics about vb.net so I didn't know what was this error about.

Comment: HELP Every form I try to open (instead if msgbox) within the if, the form sucks and the app does not execute the below commands.
Screenshot:
https://puu.sh/tWynV/8d2e3f28c6.png

Comment: @1nikolas: I suggest you create a [mcve] (make sure it is *really* both complete *and* minimal) and post a new question here.

Comment: Is this ok? its Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable:
https://puu.sh/tWH5p/464bbaf678.mp4

Comment: @1nikolas: Sorry, it's neither minimal (it contains lots of forms and code which are probably not required to reproduce the issue), nor complete ("Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem" - code is required to reproduce the problem, not a video).